# ByteArrayOutputStream from OutputStream

Tags: java

How to create OutputStream from ByteArrayOutputStream in Java

Comment: From your comments, you appear to want to create a ByteArrayOutputStream from a OutputStream.  "I get OutputStream" and "This is reverse!" Is that what you really mean?

Comment: such a bad title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following runs without error:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream outStream = stream;
```

If you see the docs for [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) you will find that it extends OutputStream.

Comment: The cast to `OutputStream` is unnecessary.

Comment: @WhiteFang34: I was just removing that.

Comment: you don't even need the intermediate stream variable. `OutputStream  outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

Answer (score 4):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` *is* a subclass of `OutputStream`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = ...;
OutputStream os = bos;
```

Comment: Im getting class cast exception in android when I do this :D

Comment: You shouldn't be. In fact assume you have control of the object, you should be doing OutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream() to begin with....

Comment: I get OutputStream from a ContentProvider, its not actually in my control.

Comment: @taranfx There will only be a ClassCastException if a cast is done. There is no cast in my example code. As MJB says, there is likely no need to deal with a ByteArrayOutputStream type directly as OutputStream contains all the relevant nominative type information.

Answer (score 2):

A [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is an [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). I.e. you can just assign it like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out = baos;
```

Comment: Reverse? What are you talking about?

Comment: I imagine that he wants a BAOS from an OutputStream ( which has been obtained from something like HttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream() ) which is also the situation i am in!

Answer (score -3):

You can create a helper method like follows:

```
public OutputStream convert(ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStreamParam){
        return arrayOutputStreamParam;
    }
```

Comment: It's useless as the ByteArrayOutputStream is an implementation of the OutputStream Interface, see the accepted answer.